# How to make an object have temporary invincibility?

Tags: python, time, pygame

I'm making a game in pygame and I need my ship to be immune for, about, 3 seconds after a collision with an asteroid. I tried every function I found, but it didn't work.

Here's the collision part of my code:

```
if collision == True:
    ship_game = ship_destroyed
    lifes -= 1;
```

And then i have this part:

```
if collision:
     pi = True
     collision = False 
     pygame.time.delay(1000)
```

This variable called pi I use in case of collision to put the ship in the middle of screen:

```
if pi == True:
     ship_game = ship
     pos_ship={'x': WScreen/2, 'y': HScreen/2}
     pi = False
```

I think that's enough for you to understand my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be accomplished by introducing a variable `collision_immune` that you set to `True`  when a collision is detected. At the same time you record the time of the last collision in a variable `collision_time`. You can get the time from `pygame.time.get_ticks()`. Then in an appropriate part of your main loop, that is not shown above, you can check if the time since the last collision is more than, say, 3 seconds and reset `collision_immune` to False. This could look something like this

```
if collision == True:
    ship_game = ship_destroyed
    lifes -= 1;
    collision_immune = True
    collision_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Then somewhere, maybe at the beginning of the main loop, you put

```
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - collision_time > 3000:    # The time is in ms.
    collision_immune = False
```

Now you can use the variable `collision_immune` in your game logic to determine if the ship is immune from a recent collision.

Happy pygaming! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the time when the last collision took place (`last_collision_time = time.time()`) and then when a collision happens you check if that value is less than 3 seconds ago (`if time.time() - last_collision_time < 3.:`) and handle it as you see fit. In this case clearly by not having the collision destroy the ship.

Answer (score 2):

OOP style:

```
class Ship:

   def immune(self):
      return self.last_collide_time > current_time() - 3000

   def collide(self):
      if self.immune(): return
      self.lifes -= 1
      self.last_collide_time = current_time()
      # ....
```